# Problems to GET with the composer - PHP

Tags: php

I created a JSON with composer to get the price of the BRL, EUR, USD coin. The program is working perfectly, however when I use the command in the cmd "php -S localhost:8000 index.php" the program is work, but function "isset($_GET['url'])" is not working in this case. FOr example, when I use "localhost:8000/exchange", need show the error: "echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error 3'));", but appear the error: "echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error 1'));"
The code of the index.php is here:

```
<?php
/**
 * Back-end Challenge.
 *
 * PHP version 7.2
 *
 * Este será o arquivo chamado na execução dos testes automátizados.
 *
 * @category Challenge
 * @package  Back-end
 * @author   Seu Nome <seu-email@seu-provedor.com>
 * @license  http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT MIT
 * @link     https://github.com/apiki/back-end-challenge
 */

declare(strict_types=1);

header('Content-Type: application/json');

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
//require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

if (isset($_GET['url'])) {
    $url = explode('/', $_GET['url']);
    //echo $url[0];
    if ($url[0] === "exchange") {

        ucfirst($url[0]);
        
        $service = 'App\Services\\'.ucfirst($url[0]).'Service';
        array_shift($url);
        if(is_numeric ($url[0])){
            $method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
            try {
                $response = call_user_func(array(new $service, $method), $url);

                
                if($response == "error"){
                    http_response_code(400);
                    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error 5'));  
                }else{
                    http_response_code(200);
                    echo json_encode(array('valorConvertido' => $response->getValor(), 'simboloMoeda' => $response->getSimbolo()));
                }
                exit;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                http_response_code(400);
                echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error 4', 'data' => $e->getMessage()), JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
                exit;
            }
        }else{ 
            http_response_code(400);
            echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error 3'));  
            exit;
        }
    }else{
        http_response_code(400);
        echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error 2'));  
        exit;
    }
}else{
    http_response_code(400);
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'error 1'));  //Always appear this error
    exit;
}
```

Someone can help me?

Comment: If you go to `/exchange` in your browser, that has nothing to do with `$_GET`. You need to look at `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` in that case. `$_GET` would be populated if, for example, you would go to `/index.php?url=exchange`

Comment: This also has nothing to do with composer (which is only a dependency manager)

Comment: Note that if you have a `.htaccess` file with a rewrite rule to map requests from `/exchange` to `/index.php?url=exchange`, this is an Apache configuration file and PHP's built-in webserver does not process those files.

Comment: thanks bro, my program is working perfectly now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the GLOBAL variable [$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server) or maybe [parse url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the url.

Answer (score 0):

To make get requests working in cmd use this:

//check if is commandline or web

```
$is_website=http_response_code()!==FALSE;
if(!$is_website){
parse_str(implode('&', array_slice($argv, 1)), $_GET);
}
```

terminal command get request usage example :
cd "/Users/fastcomputer/Google Drive/www/mybot"
php myphpfile.php username=userid password=pass